# How to prevent scroll-bars in CScrollView/CFormView-based class in MFC (Windows Mobile 6)

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, mfc, user-interface, scrollbar

I'm creating a Windows Mobile 6 application using MFC Single Document Interface with CFormView base class.

I put CBitmapButton in the Form/Dialog resource and put them at the bottom. The CBitmapButtons fit nicely until a soft-keyboard appear or the application is covered by other applications. In such case, unwanted scroll bars  appear at the bottom and at the right of the screen.

How do I remove this scroll-bars? there is neither "vertical-scroll-bar" nor "horizontal-scroll-bar" options in the dialog resource.

**Update:** CFormView is derived from CScrollView, need to inspect CScrollView
**Update:** Why would I use CFormView (derived from CScrollView) if I don't want a scroll bar? **ans:** because I want a view that can contain controls (buttons, text boxes, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buried inside MFC source code, inside `viewscrl.cpp`, lies a function called `void CScrollView::UpdateBars()`. Inside that function, there is a `gem` called `EnableScrollBarCtrl(SB_BOTH, FALSE);`

Put this function call at the end of the `OnInitialUpdate()` and it will chase away the scroll bars.

**Edit:** The `OnSize()` needs to be overriden as well not to call the parent's `OnSize()`