# How to remove only horizontal scrollbar from CScrollView

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, desktop-application

In Visual C++ with MFC, I want to remove unused horizontal scrollbar from CScrollView. I found a lot of methods, but I need vertical scrollbar. Naturally, OnSize must be overriden, not to call to base's OnSize. But vertical scrollbar must be remained, so I must call base's OnSize. For example, what will be the OnSize? Thank you. (I am not a beginner in programming, but I am a beginner in Graphic User Interface).

Update (My English is not perfect):

If the scrollbar is not required (the whole view is fit on the window), the scrollbar disappeares, but only if there is not splitter!

```
class CChildFrame: public CMDIChildWndEx {
protected:
    CSplitterWndEx  m_wndSplitter;
public:
    virtual BOOL OnCreateClient(CREATESTRUCT *, CCreateContext *const pContext) {
        return  m_wndSplitter.Create(this, 2, 1, CSize(60, 60), pContext);
    }
    // Project Wizard generated code
};
```

Without this, menu item Split in Window menu is disabled, so, does not selectable: split view does not work. How can I enable automatic disappearing with splitter?

This is independent from the splitter is enabled (there is 2 views), or does not enabled: the not required splitter does not disapper even if only 1 view is exist.

The 2 views have own vertical scrollbar, but have shared horizontal scroll bar: they are scrolled at once. But I want to set different positions. How can I create own scroll bars?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You created the cells of the splitter, but not the contents of them. You will need sthg like `m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0 ,0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyOwnView),
                                CSize(100, 100), pContext);
    m_wndSplitter.CreateView(1, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyOwnView),
                                CSize(100, 100), pContext);` after. Later you can get each view with code as `CMyOwnView *pSubView = (CMyOwnView*) m_wndSplitter.GetPane(0, 1);`

Comment: The menu does this: Window / Split. Originally there is only 1 view, the menu creates the other. I tried, works, but there is common horizontal scrollbar (I can not set different positions at the 2 views), and what is not disappeared if does not required (the whole view is fit in the window).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a thing simple as `yourScrollView->ShowScrollBar(SB_HORZ, FALSE)` ?

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#showscrollbar

Comment: This has no effect. I put this to both InitialUpdate and OnSize, before and after all call of base's function.

Comment: Try to override `OnPrepareDC`, call `ShowScrollBar` there and call `__super::OnPrepareDC` after. may be this is the wrong order.

Comment: Alternative interesting answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423483/383779

Comment: And if you don't want any scrolling at all, why aren't you using a `CView` instead of a `ScrollView`?

Comment: I need vertical scrollbar.

Comment: `EnableScrollBarCtrl(SB_HORZ, FALSE);` and `EnableScrollBarCtrl(SB_VERT, TRUE);` perhaps?

Comment: Has no effect in OnPrepareDC so, I tried in both order.

Comment: The cause was the splitter, I supplemented the question.

Comment: The problem is scope. You are thinking you are doing things in splitter sub-windows, when in reality you are touching in the splitter window or in the window containing it. Without you showing more of your code, it is all I can say.

Comment: I supplemented the code. There is no other modifying compared with the project wizard generated code (what affects the split).